# MudBlazor's MudChip Default true not working

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

When rendering MudChip items from fetched API data, the property "Default" doesn't work.
Can you help me on this please?

```
            <MudChipSet @bind-SelectedChips="selected" MultiSelection="true" Filter="true">
            <MudChip Text="Test1" Default="true" /> <!-- This works -->
            <MudChip Text="Test2" Default="true" /> <!-- This works -->

            @if (UserMenuList == null)
            {
                <MudChip Text="Loading..." Disabled="true" />
            }
            else
            {
                @foreach (var item in UserMenuList.OrderBy(o => o.Name))
                {
                    <MudChip Text="@item.Name" Tag="item" Default="true" /> <!-- This does not -->
                }
            }
        </MudChipSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem was tracked and solved in [this github issue](https://github.com/Garderoben/MudBlazor/pull/1446). If you are unable to update MudBlazor, the workaround would be to wrap the whole chipset in your `else` statement:

```html
@if (UserMenuList == null)
{
    <span>Loading ... </span>
}
else
{
    <MudChipSet @bind-SelectedChips="selected" MultiSelection="true" Filter="true">
        <MudChip Text="Test1" Default="true" /> 
        <MudChip Text="Test2" Default="true" /> 
        @foreach (var item in UserMenuList.OrderBy(o => o.Name))
        {
            <MudChip Text="@item.Name" Tag="item" Default="true" />
        }
    </MudChipSet>
}
```